# How do I align my text div next to my image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display my text next to my image. The image info with social links need to stay below the image. I've tried clearfix codes but no result has worked sufficiently. I am working with a bootstrap build and I may be missing something simple, thus I've left in all my html in case I moved something (can't see that I did though). I've included the specific css as well although I have global code too (not added here). Any suggestions?

```css
#team {
  padding: 60px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#team h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#team .team {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#team .team h4 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#team .team p {
  color: #a3a3a3;
}
#team .team a {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#team .team a:hover,
#team .team a:focus,
#team .team a:active {
  color: #a3a3a3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>INFO</h2>
    <hr class="sep">
    <p>MORE INFO</p>
    <div class="row wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="IMAGE FILE" alt="THIS IS AN IMAGE">
        <h4>NAME</h4>
        <p>PROFESSION</p>
        <div class="team-social-icons">
          <a href="***" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="***" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="***" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you want the h4 to be on the side of the picture? Or which text exactly?

Comment: It was just the lorem ipsum text that needed to be beside the image.

Comment: Ok great. Then run my code snippet in my answer. I got ya!

Comment: you should not add an answer in the context you did. I suggest you delete it because I am sure someone will down vote it. It is not really what meets the guidelines of this site. That being said my answer should help you a lot if you read it and try to understand it. You are using a very powerful tool. Once you understand bootstrap you will never have problems like this again. if my answer helped you please accept it and upvote so it can help someone else too!

Comment: Thanks I'll keep it in mind. I actually found my code was fine. Brackets wasn't updating my live view. I may need to look into another platform for future use.

Comment: If you are just starting out try dream weaver if you can get your hands on it. Sometimes these powerful programs can be hard to learn too. Just stay focused don't get discouraged and keep trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Align text to the side of an image.

**Solution**

If you want text to sit on the side of the image you need to add a `float` to the image.

your code is going to need more css to obtain your complete desired result but to get you going you should create a class to add to the image which will have the `float: left;` property.

```
.floatImg { float: left;}
```

Then apply it to the image,

```
<img class="floatImg">
```

To show you a small example of this all I did was add a float to your image existing class. "but you should create a new one". Then I moved the h4 above the image so the `<p>` would wrap. Once you apply this to your project you can apply more `css` to make it all look nice.

`Padding / margin` etc

**Bootstrap**

Luckily you are using `bootstrap`. So to take this a step further there is a lot of options here you can use to make this look nice. Bootstrap gives you the ability to use `columns` and `rows`.

So if you know you need to create a 2 column row. `img` in one and text in the other you could do that.

**Example of bootstrap 2 col**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
          <img>
    <div>  
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
         <p> txt here</p>
    <div>    
</div>
```

```css
#team {
  padding: 60px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#team h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#team .team {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#team .team h4 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#team .team p {
  color: #a3a3a3;
}
#team .team a {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#team .team a:hover,
#team .team a:focus,
#team .team a:active {
  color: #a3a3a3;
}

.img-responsive {
  float: left;
  }
```

```html
<section id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>INFO</h2>
    <hr class="sep">
    <p>MORE INFO</p>
    <div class="row wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
      <div class="col-md-4">
<h4>NAME</h4>
        <p>PROFESSION</p>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="IMAGE FILE" alt="THIS IS AN IMAGE">
        
        <div class="team-social-icons">
          <a href="***" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="***" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="***" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I didn't think to float the image, I kept trying to float the div... I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: Ya there a ton of ways to accomplish any problems. Depending on your end goal it is hard to say what would be better. I suggest you think of this project as a grid. Draw it on paper if you need labeling each column. Then Focus on creating the boxes on the screen then go back and add the content once all the boxes are sitting where you want them.

Answer (score -2):

A `<div>`'s content will go to the next line, adding a break before it. I would look at organising the layout into a `<table>` with a left `<td>` for the image, and a right `<td>` for the description and the links to social media.

Comment: No, you absolutely should not.